# How to insert into custom table

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization to the Invoice and Memo screen, where I have a completely custom table to which I want to write an error log entry.  Since this doesn't really fit with how the training addresses the issue - is there a way to do this directly?  I noticed that there's a PXInsert<> command - but there's no documentation that I could find, either in the Framework help, or here  on Stack Overflow.

I know I can create a Cache object for my custom table's DAC and use the Insert command of that Cache - but I don't know the exact syntax for doing that (and I couldn't find a good fit for what I'm trying to do in the training manuals).  Maybe I missed it.

Comment: Peter, could you please provide an example of "an error log entry", that you want to write in your custom table?

Comment: INSERT INTO tblErrorLog ([DateTime], [Type], [ErrorMessage])
VALUES (GetDate(),  'Error', 'The field is invalid')

I just want to do a simple insert into a table.

Comment: I guess you want to write an error log entry when user clicks on Save and some of the changes doesn't successfully go through, is that correct?

Comment: Not necessarily.  I'm calling an Acumatica web service from inside the graph extension, and if there's an error in the execution I want to log the message that is returned.  I think EricP (below) answered my question...if that works.  Haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Peter, just so you know, Web Services are primarily designed for integration with 3rd party applications, not to create communication between screens inside Acumatica - for this purpose you have to do all the staff in C# and utilize capabilities of the Acumatica Framework. Using Web Services in such scenarios is highly not recommended as it will slow down performance, utilize additional resources to establish yet another unnecessary user session and eventually will add some maintenance cost in long-term prospective.

Comment: I realize that.  We're using it because we're integrating into another company, with its own login.  I'm not sure how to do that within one company instance.

Comment: To execute some code under another company, you should put your code within `using (new PXLoginScope(...))` context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to create a Cache object (or I think you might be thinking of a graph) is to use PXGraph object. Here is an example:

```
private void Function()
{
  //TargetGraph is the name of the custom page
  TargetGraph graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<TargetGraph>();
  //TargetDAC is the name of the custom DAC in your customizations
  TargetDAC dac = new TargetDAC();
  //Set all data to dac
  dac.Log = log;
  //Finally insert and perform the save action for the graph
  graph.LogView.Insert(dac);
  graph.Actions.PressSave();
}
```

Perhaps someone could add to this answer on how to grab the errors from the page if that is also what you need.

Comment: Is 'LogView' a view declared in the Graph extension?  Such as 
public PXSelect<MyDAC> LogView;   ?

Comment: Yes, that would be how it is declared in the Graph extension. MyDac would instead be TargetDAC just to stay consistent with the example I gave above.

Comment: I'm confused.  If I'm declaring that view in a graph extension, how would it show up as a property of the main graph?

Comment: The view does not have to be defined within the extension of the graph you are customizing. You can create a new graph, define the view on that, and then use that graph to create an instance of itself on another page with that view. I haven't really tinkered with creating custom views within graph extensions yet, so I cannot answer that question.

Comment: Thanks EricP - I've created a new graph class and put the view there.  Everything compiles fine, I just have to deploy and test it.

Thanks much!

Comment: Ideally you don't need to create a separate instance of a BLC to save something in DB (as it's time and resource consuming), unless you need to have all the business logic invoked automating what users can do in UI. I can see the need to create a BLC if someone wants to create or update a Sales Order or an Inventory Item, but it's just too heavy and complicated solution to insert some logging stuff in database.

Comment: Ruslan - Do you have any kind of example for what you're suggesting?  I just need to log to a custom table - this should be simple.  I've implemented the solution above, but since my ID field is an auto-incrementing bigint field, I get an error when trying to write to it.  Is there a 'best practice', such as NOT using an auto-incrementing key field in a table?

Comment: I ended up using a stored procedure, with my BLC code passing the parameters I want to log.  This whole BQL and graph logic wasn't doing the job for the reasons stated above.

Comment: You could try making a view within the graph that pulls in views associated with the ID of the main object of the page. Then just make a new obejct with that view object, fill it, and use .Insert() to add it to the DB. If you want an example, I can add it to my answer.